# Framer-motion does not stagger children, no matter what I try

Tags: animation, jsx, framer-motion, framerjs

My JSX:

```
 <motion.div className={styles.aboutGreeting}
                    variants={containerVariants}
                    initial='hidden'
                    animate='visible'
                    >
                    <motion.h4 className={styles.firstLine}
                        variants={dropUpVariants}
                    >
                        Hi, I&apos;m
                    </motion.h4>
                    <motion.h1 className={styles.highlight}
                        variants={dropUpVariants}
                    >
                        John Doe
                    </motion.h1>
                    <motion.h1 className={styles.title}
                        variants={dropUpVariants}
                    >
                        I&apos;m a front-end web developer.
                    </motion.h1>
                </motion.div>
```

My variants:

```
export const containerVariants = {
    hidden: {
        opacity: .6
    },
    visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
            staggerChildren: 0.5
        }
    }

}
export const dropUpVariants = {
    hidden: {
        y: '100vw'
    },
    visible: {
        y: 0,
        transition: {
            type: 'spring', stiffness: 100, mass: .3,
            delay: .3
        }
    }
}
```

As the title suggests, the animations do play, but there is no stagger effect. The three children of aboutGreeting all play their animation at once. Of course I can set a manual delay, but I'd like the "staggerChildren" property to work, to be honest. Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Framer/Framer Motion, when you are using `staggerChildren` in a parent variant and the `delay` property on children variants, the delay property will take precedence, starting all child animations at once.

For this to work you will need to remove the `delay: .3` property on dropUpVariants.

Here's a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-framer-motion-does-not-stagger-children-no-matter-what-i-try-vnuuc4

```
export const containerVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      delayChildren: 0, // this will set a delay before the children start animating
      staggerChildren: 0.3 // this will set the time inbetween children animation
    }
  }
};
export const dropUpVariants = {
  hidden: {
    y: "100vw"
  },
  visible: {
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 100,
      mass: 0.3
      // remove delay: 0.3,
    }
  }
};
```